# When the bullet hits, the cowboys should fall down and a message should be shown

Tags: javascript, canvas, bounce, bullet

When the page loads cowboys shoots a bullet and then it bounces back from the right wall and hits the  cowboy. He falls down with the(felldownCowboy()) and then show a message. How can I stop the bullet and show the message? I can't find the solution!  The cowboy is made by canvas

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var hit = 0;
var x = 500;
var xdir = 1;

function trigger() {
  if (x == 1000 || x == 400) {

    xdir = -1 * xdir
  }


  if (xdir == 1) {
    x = x + 5;
  } else {
    x = x - 5;
  }

  if (xdir == 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw2Cowboy);
  } else if (hit == 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw2Cowboy);
  }



  requestAnimationFrame(bullet);

}


function drawCowboy() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 300);
  //head
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150, 390, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  // body
  ctx.moveTo(150, 450);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  ctx.lineWidth = 12;
  ctx.stroke();

  // left arm
  ctx.moveTo(10, 600);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 540);
  ctx.stroke();

  // right arm
  ctx.moveTo(300, 500);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 540);
  ctx.stroke();


  // left leg
  ctx.moveTo(-30, 900);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  ctx.stroke();

  // right leg
  ctx.moveTo(300, 900);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  ctx.stroke();


  // gun
  ctx.moveTo(300, 450);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 540);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 470);
  ctx.lineTo(400, 470);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.closePath();
}


// drawCowboy();


function felldownCowboy() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 300);
  //head
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(380, 720, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  // body
  ctx.moveTo(350, 750);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  ctx.lineWidth = 12;
  // left arm
  ctx.moveTo(150, 650);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 700);
  // right arm
  ctx.moveTo(450, 950);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 700);
  // left leg
  ctx.moveTo(-30, 900);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  // right leg
  ctx.moveTo(300, 900);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 640);
  ctx.stroke()

}



function bullet() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
  ctx.beginPath();
  var draw = ctx.arc(x, 470, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
}

requestAnimationFrame(bullet);
setInterval(trigger, 20);
```

```html
<h1>A cowboy never dies</h1>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=canvas+collision+detection+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)